# Why do airline toilets delay for a few seconds before flushing?

Tags: airliner, aircraft-systems, passenger

I have noticed that when I push the toilet flush button in a regular passenger airliner, it takes several seconds (perhaps 2 or 3) before the toilet actually flushes.

What is the reason for this delay?

Comment: Probably charging the flux capacitors.

Answer (score 3):

Most passenger aircraft of today (747, A380, widebodies of any kind) use vacuum-flush toilets.  It takes time for that system to go through. It also has to coordinate lids into the waste storage container that is usually fireproofed.

Those 2 seconds took decades to develop and keeps the odor and fires out!